# How can we pause and resume the steps in the Spring batch?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

i am working on spring-batch and checking the possibilities of **pausing the steps**.

Actually before we have 11 jobs and we tried before to pause/resume the job and it is worked well.

But now we changed those 11 job within a single job and configured every job as steps and in this situation how can we pause/ resume the steps?

```
return jobBuilderFactory.get("incomingjob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(jobListener)
                .preventRestart()
                .start(startFirst()).on("*").to(secondStep())
                .on("*").to(thirdStep())
                .on("*").to(fourthStep())
                .on("*").to(fifth())
                .on("*").to(sixth())
                .on("*").to(seventh())
                .on("*").to(eighth())
                .on("*").to(ninth())
                .on("*").to(tenth())
                .build().build();
```

it would be helpful if anyone share your thoughts regarding this?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. This feature has been removed since v2. You can find more details in the following issues:

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/2626
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1633